# how can I have a non editable text field accept keyboard input if its selected?

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard, textfield, scene

if I have a non editable textfield in a scene and have

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> keyboardControls(event));
```

and that `keyboardControls()` lets me append things to the textfield. Why does it not work when the textfield is selected. how can I fix this?

Is there a way to make the textfield non selectable without disabling it?

(Or making it not look disabled?)

Comment: All `modena.css` does when a node is disabled is [set the opacity to `0.4`](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css#L523). Simply doing `field.setOpacity(1)` should make it not looked disabled (setting properties programmatically takes priority over styles from the user-agent style sheet).

Comment: please be precise: what do you mean by _textfield is selected_? Technical terms are either _textField's text is selected_ or _textField is focused_ .. Anyway, [mcve] required demonstrating what exactly you want to achieve and how it doesn't work. Curious: why do you want a not-editable textField to receive keyEvents? That's not how it's supposed to be used (though possible)